# Know if you run through the application or through the website

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I have an application built with Html5 and PhoneGap.

how can I know (in JS) if you run the application or running the Html5(web)?

Comment: there is a thing called User Agent ...

Comment: Can you show an example of using it?

Comment: You can check for the properties phonegap adds to the window-object like `if (window.Media){/* do phonegap */}`

Comment: There is a way to know this in js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[definition and usage of the userAgent property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_useragent.asp).

the navigation object has also a platform property ([further information](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_navigator.asp)).

i hope it helps!